# Выдернуть часть строки

Tags: delphi

Есть строки такого типа:

```
Nomer_tovara: 557436
Brend: VMS
Garantiya: 2343454
Year : 2019

Nomer_tovara: 557436
Brend: ORP
Garantiya: 78788777
Year : 2019

И строки постоянно повторяются....
```

Как вытянуть текст после **Brend:** и **Garantiya:** и Соединить их через знак двоеточие :.

**Выходной файл должен быть:**

```
VMS:2343454
ORP:78788777
```

Хотел сделать вот так, Но это только позволяет найти эти строки. В итоге провал и ничего не получилось:

```
if (PosEx('Brend:', s) > 0) or (PosEx('Garantiya:', s) > 0) then
  writeln(Out1, S);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  sl, sl_out: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl_out := TStringList.Create;
  sl.NameValueSeparator := ':';
  sl.LoadFromFile(...);
  for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if sl.Names[i] = 'Brend' then
      s := Trim(sl.ValueFromIndex[i]);
    if sl.Names[i] = 'Garantiya' then
    begin
      s := s + ':' + Trim(sl.ValueFromIndex[i]);
      sl_out.Add(s);
    end;
  end;
  sl_out.SaveToFile(...);
  sl_out.Free;
  sl.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Я немного перепутал. Сначала подумал что код заработал, но потом увидел что не обрабатывает как нужно файл. Просто тоже самое выдает, в чем конфликт ? То есть при сохранении в файл не работает.

Comment: А что Вы сохраняете в файл? Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Теперь работает, это была моя ошибка.  Получается я сохранял и сам файл и ответ в один файл не  создав переменную sl_out. Спасибо Вам dr. F.I.N.